# How to delete image with multi delete?

Tags: laravel

I have multi delete I need when delete `news`  delete the image of each new that I selected

Controller code:

```
public function delMulti(Request $request)
{
    if(is_array($request->muti_delete)){

        News::destroy($request->muti_delete);
    }else{

        News::find($request->muti_delete)->delete();
    }
    return redirect()->back();
}

$request->muti_delete -> array of ids of news
```

My own dick for images:

```
Storage::disk('public_uploads')->delete('news/'. $news->image);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the news have id? Try this

```
News::whereIn('id', $request->muti_delete)->get()->each(function($msg) {
    Storage::disk('public_uploads')->delete('news/'. $msg->image);
    $msg->delete();
});
```

At first, we need get all news with get(). each() function just the same with foreach(). It will execute codes for each news. If I use foreach() the code will be like this

```
$messages = News::whereIn('id', $request->muti_delete)->get();

foreach ($messages as $msg) {
    $this->delete_image($msg->image);
    $msg->delete();
}
```

And I think you should create function for deleting image, so it will looks more clear.

Comment: what's each() and for what this fun can you explain it briefly pls?

Comment: each is loop through your all get records. same as jquery .each

Answer (score 1):

Use This code

```
$image_path = "/images/filename.ext";  // Value is not URL but directory file path
if(File::exists($image_path)) {
    File::delete($image_path);
}
```